# Is there any side effects for Runtime.getRuntime().gc()

Tags: java, performance, coding-style, garbage-collection, runtime

I like to know is there any side effect of using `Runtime.getRuntime().gc()` in our programs explicitly ?

Or is it a good practice to use the same code for better performance ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Runtime.getRuntime().gc()` can cause side effects.

1. `Runtime.getRuntime().gc()` - does not guarantee that gc will run
2. `Runtime.getRuntime().gc()` - as specified by documentation  this will hint the GC that it can act, and if GC decides that is ready to run it might overlap the application processing threads and cause delays and slowness.

It is recommended that this should not be used, instead try tunning the GC in order for the system to behave correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you use Runtime.getRuntime().gc() there is no guarantee that memory will be free

Comment: Yes, It is not guarantee that JVM will call garbage collector or not. We cant predict that. JVM will collect when memory is almost full  , that for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you use `Runtime.getRuntime().gc()` your program will potentailly slow down.